# Delete threaded mails in evolution

Tags: 10.10, evolution

How do I delete all emails in a thread in evolution? It is really a difficult task to delete them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be no function to remove the complete thread.

But you can select any message in this thread and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to select the complete thread. Now you can delete all selected messages.

Tip: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> only selects the subthread of your current message.

Comment: Thanks david. It would have been better if there is a single shortcut to delete the entire thread. Will it land on 11.04?..